# Constants File Variables/Data members being collected by GC with message Object has been colleted through Watches in Android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, constants

I have a Class `FrameworkKeys` where I am keeping all the static members that remain constant throughout the android app as shown below

```
public class FrameworkKeys {
    public static final int HURL_MODE = 1;
    public static final int SHUFFLE_MODE = 2;
    public static final int LEVEL_COMPLETED = 1;
    public static final int LEVEL_FAILED = 0;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_1 = 10;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_2 = 20;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_3 = 30;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_4 = 40;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_5 = 50;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_6 = 60;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_7 = 70;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_8 = 80;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_9 = 90;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_10 = 100;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_11 = 110;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_12 = 120;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_13 = 130;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_14 = 140;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_15 = 150;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_16 = 160;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_17 = 170;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_18 = 180;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_19 = 190;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_20 = 200;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_21 = 210;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_22 = 220;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_23 = 230;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_24 = 240;
    public static final int BONUS_LEVEL_25 = 250;
}
```

The issue is that while I am executing the code everywhere it works fine except one

I am executing a `Runnable` with `postDelayed` and from there on I call a method in the activity `runOnUiThread` which uses the values eg. `FrameworkKeys.BONUS_LEVEL_25` which shows an unexpected problem causing bugs that is **Object has been collected**